# Getting Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout on @aws-sdk/client-s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was trying to upload a file to s3 using v3 SDK but I can't do it because of the Socket timeout error even though I have valid IAM credentials.

```
const s3 = new S3Client({
region: process.env.AWS_REGION || '',
credentials: {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '',
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || '',
},
```

});

This is how I initialized the s3 object, I even tried by extending the timeout, still didn't work.

```
 const s3 = new S3Client({
region: process.env.AWS_REGION || '',
credentials: {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '',
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || '',
},
requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
  connectionTimeout: 10000,
  requestTimeout: 10000,
})
```

});

Comment: Socket timeout indicates a network problem, not a credentials problem.  If your credentials were wrong you'd get a permission denied message.  Does the machine you're running on have a proxy or other firewall?

Comment: hey thanks - but no, i haven't set up any proxy or firewall on my machine (localhost)

Answer (score 4):

I had this error every 10-20 runs of the app. Fixed thanks to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47822

The first solution is to upgrade the Node version to `20.3.0` or higher.

Second is `setDefaultAutoSelectFamily(false)`

```
// Work around a node v20.0.0, v20.1.0, and v20.2.0 bug. The issue was fixed
// in v20.3.0.
// https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47822#issuecomment-1564708870
// Safe to remove once support for Node v20 is dropped.
if (
  // !process.env.IS_BROWSER && // uncomment this line if you use a bundler that sets env.IS_BROWSER during build time
  process.versions &&
  // check for `node` in case we want to use this in "exotic" JS envs
  process.versions.node &&
  process.versions.node.match(/20\.[0-2]\.0/)
) {
  require("net").setDefaultAutoSelectFamily(false);
}
```

I tested that this fix works.

Comment: Updating Node from 20.2.0 to 20.3.0 fixed the issue