# AWS CDK fails to deploy to regions such as Cape Town(af-south-1) and Sanpro(sa-east-1)

Tags: aws-cdk

I am working in Japan.
When I cdk deploy to the regions of Cape Town, Africa(af-south-1) or Sao Paulo, South America(sa-east-1), I get an error "Failed to publish asset" and it fails.

AWS CDK 2.130.0
Node.js v20.1.0

```
% npx cdk deploy MyStack --verbose
...

✨  Synthesis time: 2.55s

[12:08:20] Checking for previously published assets
[12:08:20] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
[12:08:20] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/cdk-hoge-deploy-role-999999999999-af-south-1'.
[12:08:20] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
[12:08:20] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/cdk-hoge-deploy-role-999999999999-af-south-1'.
[12:08:22] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
[12:08:22] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/cdk-hoge-file-publishing-role-999999999999-af-south-1'.
[12:08:22] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
[12:08:22] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/cdk-hoge-file-publishing-role-999999999999-af-south-1'.
[12:08:24] MyStack:  check: Check s3://cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1/b1359618ca81e388a5c42b1aa176748b2a9c0410a591d1a6ebafd39294e0907c.json
[12:08:24] MyStack:  check: Check s3://cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1/b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6.zip
[12:08:37] Call failed: listObjectsV2({"Bucket":"cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1","Prefix":"b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6.zip","MaxKeys":1}) => Socket connection timeout (code=NetworkingError)
[12:08:37] MyStack:  debug: Socket connection timeout
[12:08:41] Call failed: listObjectsV2({"Bucket":"cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1","Prefix":"b1359618ca81e388a5c42b1aa176748b2a9c0410a591d1a6ebafd39294e0907c.json","MaxKeys":1}) => Socket connection timeout (code=NetworkingError)
[12:08:41] MyStack:  debug: Socket connection timeout
[12:08:41] 2 total assets, 2 still need to be published
[12:08:41] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
MyStack:  start: Building b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6:999999999999-af-south-1
MyStack:  success: Built b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6:999999999999-af-south-1
[12:08:44] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
MyStack:  start: Building b1359618ca81e388a5c42b1aa176748b2a9c0410a591d1a6ebafd39294e0907c:999999999999-af-south-1
MyStack:  success: Built b1359618ca81e388a5c42b1aa176748b2a9c0410a591d1a6ebafd39294e0907c:999999999999-af-south-1
[12:08:44] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
MyStack:  start: Publishing b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6:999999999999-af-south-1
[12:08:44] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
MyStack:  start: Publishing b1359618ca81e388a5c42b1aa176748b2a9c0410a591d1a6ebafd39294e0907c:999999999999-af-south-1
[12:08:44] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
[12:08:44] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/cdk-hoge-file-publishing-role-999999999999-af-south-1'.
[12:08:44] Retrieved account ID 999999999999 from disk cache
[12:08:44] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/cdk-hoge-file-publishing-role-999999999999-af-south-1'.
[12:08:45] MyStack:  check: Check s3://cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1/b1359618ca81e388a5c42b1aa176748b2a9c0410a591d1a6ebafd39294e0907c.json
[12:08:45] MyStack:  check: Check s3://cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1/b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6.zip
[12:08:54] Call failed: getBucketLocation({"Bucket":"cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1"}) => Socket connection timeout (code=NetworkingError)
MyStack:  fail: Socket connection timeout
[12:09:00] Call failed: getBucketLocation({"Bucket":"cdk-hoge-assets-999999999999-af-south-1"}) => Socket connection timeout (code=NetworkingError)
MyStack:  fail: Socket connection timeout

 ❌ Deployment failed: Error: Failed to publish asset b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6:999999999999-af-south-1
    at Deployments.publishSingleAsset (/Users/hoge/my-stack/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:430:11655)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.publishAsset (/Users/hoge/my-stack/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:430:194847)
    at async /Users/hoge/my-stack/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:430:178995
[12:09:00] Reading cached notices from /Users/hoge/.cdk/cache/notices.json

Failed to publish asset b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6:999999999999-af-south-1
[12:09:00] Error: Failed to publish asset b7f33614a69548d6bafe224d751a7ef238cde19097415e553fe8b63a4c8fd8a6:999999999999-af-south-1
    at Deployments.publishSingleAsset (/Users/tatsuto/my-stack/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:430:11655)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.publishAsset (/Users/tatsuto/my-stack/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:430:194847)
    at async /Users/tatsuto/my-stack/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:430:178995
```

It seems that a Socket connection timeout occurs and fails in listObjectsV2 and getBucketLocation for the bucket created by cdk bootstrap, but no failures occur when executing the AWS CLI command s3api.
It seems that the Socket connection timeout occurs during the internal operation of the CDK Toolkit.

How can I cdk deploy successfully?
I would like to know if there are any valid options, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a bug in Node.js v20.
The solution is to upgrade the Node version to 20.3.0 or higher.

[Getting Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout on @aws-sdk/client-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76878175/getting-error-err-socket-connection-timeout-socket-connection-timeout-on-aws)

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47822